# Alternatives for multi currency web application

Tags: firebase, vue.js, localization, internationalization, currency

I want to develop my own web application on Vue.js and Firebase where uses can buy products or services using a payment API (paypal or stripe).

I would like to show the prices of these products in local currency of each user, but I dont figure out how to approach the problem. Perhaps using a currency conversion external API?

Please if anybody has faced this problem once I would like to know what alternatives (libraries, api, code samples...) exist to solve this on Vue.js and Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to find the common exchange rates for the currency on the client. Re-calculating the prices in your database is inefficient. instead, you store the current trading value from a source and multiply that from your base value.

USD to RUPE is 1203% - simply multiplying the value by `1203`will render it as the correct price

There are several sources that offer exchange rates, this could be an npm package like the following: https://www.npmjs.com/package/currency-converter

Comment: okay so if i understood: i save the prices on USD at database, and in frontend I call the api to get the conversion before showing the price in local currency. But how do I get the local currency code of the user?

Comment: Correct, else you risk blowing out your bill and corrupting your data for all users

Comment: But how do I get the local currency code of the user? Is there any package for vue.js to do this?

Comment: if you tried manually updating all entries in your database to 12 different currencies at the same time, you have corrupted values as one client updates the values to another. it's in general - bad practice. recalculating it on the client is the best way.

Comment: you can read the users regional location, and you can make the assumption there.

`(73.57).toLocaleString('de-DE',{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}); // German: 73,57 €`

- -
`(73.57).toLocaleString('en-US',{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}); // American: €73.57`

Comment: okay so maybe i will need some JSON relating location code with currency i.e: `{"es-ES":"EUR", "de-DE":"EUR", "en-US":"USD"}` right?

Comment: sounds reasonable and im sure you can find some npm packages that offer the same